# How to convert HTML table to JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, html-table, converters

I'm trying to convert HTML tables to JSON in Python, but I'm still using the traditional way, how to make it more modern and automated, whether it's using libraries or whatever

The table that I want to change is the table on this website:
[Badan-Pusat-Statistic](https://www.archive.bps.go.id/indicator/2/1699/1/persentase-penduduk-usia-5-tahun-ke-atas-yang-pernah-mengakses-internet-dalam-3-bulan-terakhir-menurut-provinsi-dan-kemampuan-membaca.html)

I tried scraping and retrieving the data this way, but this is too manual and too traditional, is there a more modern and easier approach?

```
response: Response = requests.get(url=__url)
html: PyQuery = PyQuery(response.text)

if not html.find('thead tr th:nth-child(2)'):
    break
__url_val += 1

__urls_tables.append(__url)

tables = self.__parser.ex(html=html, selector='#tablex')
if len(tables.find(selector='thead tr')) > 2:
    
    __headers = []
    for head in tables.find(selector='thead tr:first-child th'):
        __headers.append(re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', head.text.strip()))

    __key_layer2 = []
    for head in tables.find(selector='thead tr:nth-child(2) th'):
        __key_layer2.append(re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', head.text.strip()))

    __key_layer3 = []
    for head in tables.find(selector='thead tr:nth-child(3) th'):
        __key_layer3.append(re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', head.text.strip()).replace('\u2009', ' '))

    for value in tables.find(selector='tbody tr'):
        __data_table = {
            __headers[0]: self.__parser.ex(html=value, selector='td:first-child').text(),
            __headers[1]: {
                layer2: {
                    __key_layer3[i]: self.filter_data(self.__parser.ex(html=value, selector=f'td:nth-child({i + 2 + int(len(__key_layer3) / len(__key_layer2)) * index_layer2})').text())
                    for i in range(int(len(__key_layer3) / len(__key_layer2)))

                } for index_layer2, layer2 in enumerate(__key_layer2)
            }
        }
```

I hope you deign to see clearer code here: https://github.com/ryosoraa/Bps-scraping.PY/blob/main/libs/service/html_parser.py

The result I was hoping for was JSON like this

```json
{
  "Type": "EKONOMI",
  "times": "2023-12-06 23:04:02.498650",
  "datas": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Persentase Penduduk Usia 5 Tahun ke Atas yang Pernah Mengakses Internet dalam 3 Bulan Terakhir menurut Provinsi dan Kemampuan Membaca, 2014-2022",
        "update": "27 Sep 2023",
        "keterangan": "Statistik Dasar",
        "url_tables": [
          "https://www.archive.bps.go.id/indicator/2/1699/1/persentase-penduduk-usia-5-tahun-ke-atas-yang-pernah-mengakses-internet-dalam-3-bulan-terakhir-menurut-provinsi-dan-kemampuan-membaca.html",
          "https://www.archive.bps.go.id/indicator/2/1699/2/persentase-penduduk-usia-5-tahun-ke-atas-yang-pernah-mengakses-internet-dalam-3-bulan-terakhir-menurut-provinsi-dan-kemampuan-membaca.html",
          "https://www.archive.bps.go.id/indicator/2/1699/3/persentase-penduduk-usia-5-tahun-ke-atas-yang-pernah-mengakses-internet-dalam-3-bulan-terakhir-menurut-provinsi-dan-kemampuan-membaca.html"
        ],
        "data_tables": [
          {
            "Provinsi": "ACEH",
            "Persentase Penduduk Usia 5 Tahun ke Atas yang Pernah Mengakses Internet dalam 3 Bulan Terakhir menurut Provinsi dan Kemampuan Membaca (Persen)": {
              "Dapat Membaca": {
                "2020": "99.23",
                "2021": "99.07",
                "2022": "98.98",
                "2017": "99.88",
                "2018": "99.81",
                "2019": "99.53",
                "2014": "99.97",
                "2015": "99.98",
                "2016": "99.85"
              },
              "Tidak Dapat Membaca": {
                "2020": "0.77",
                "2021": "0.93",
                "2022": "1.02",
                "2017": "0.12",
                "2018": "0.19",
                "2019": "0.47",
                "2014": "0.03",
                "2015": "0.02",
                "2016": "0.15"
              }
            }
          }
```

Because the data is too big, I can't add them all

I hope you can see the full results here: https://github.com/ryosoraa/Bps-scraping.PY/blob/main/data/EKONOMI/KOMUNIKASI.json